# Alamofire deallocated session cancelled

Tags: swift, alamofire

Can I get some help finding where my SessionManager is being deallocated? Receiving an Alamofire Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 “canceled” and just can't seem to get around it or make sense out of the many other duplicate issues related to this same error on stackoverflow?

thx

Here is my NetworkManager Class NetworkManager.swift

```swift
class NetworkManager {

    var defaultManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "myserver.net": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: false,
                validateHost: false
            ),


        ]

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }()
}
```

And my ViewController.swift

```swift
func downloadspeakerData(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {


    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [

        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "User-Agent": "iOS;iOS"

    ]


    NetworkManager.init().defaultManager.request(qaSpeakerUrl, headers: headers).validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            //print(Data.self)
            print(response)

            let result = response.result
            //print(result)
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                if let list = dict["d"]?["results"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    let titleDetails = list[0]["SpeakerName"] as? String

                    self._title = titleDetails

                    for obj in list {
                        let speaker = Speaker(speakerDict: obj)
                        self.speakers.append(speaker)

                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            completed()

        }


        .authenticate(user: ("\(userfinal.0)"), password: ("\(userfinal.1)"))
}
```

Comment: The definition of the **NetworkManager.defaultManager** property returns a new instance of **Alamofire.SessionManager** every time it is called(NetworkManager.defaultManager). If this is **not** by design this could be a/the problem.

More importantly, in your view controller try to store the **NetworkManager.defaultManager** that you get when you call **NetworkManager.init().defaultManager** in a new local property **ViewControler.manager** and then issue the call using this new variable. If this is a scope issue, this should work.

Comment: Thanks @infinite-loop Problem was I had more than one Alamofire request in another view controller that wasn't using the sessionManager, also noticed that my certificate pinning wasnt working properly.